# how to create a stack of widgets that overlap possibly using listview builder

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a list of sized box widgets that will overlap using the stack method. This would be similar to the listview builder, from a list that is constantly changing but I am lost as to how you could return a stack of positioned, sized boxes from a listview builder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a builder method for stack or indexedstack. You could use List.generate() to dynamically generate your widget build.